# AllowAnonymous attribute in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, authorize

```
[Authorize] // Derived from Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Authorize
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous] // [AllowAnonymous] doesn't be supported here
    public async Task GetEmails()
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var users = await db.Users.ToListAsync();
            var emails = new List<string>();
            users.ForEach(x => emails.Add(x.Email));
            Clients.All.getEmails(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emails));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem: I'd set breakpoint to `GetEmails` method but it's never hit to. Then, I signed in and tried again, it's working.

That means: `[System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]` doen't work within `[Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Authorize]`.

So, my question is: Why doesn't namespace `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` support `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute? And do I need to declare `AllowAnonymous` attribute for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem: Using `[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]` instead of `[Authorize]`. Like this:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize] 
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous] 
    public async Task GetEmails()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I don't understand why but it should work perfectly :)

Comment: خود گویی و خود خندی - What's your platform?