# Attribute AllowAnonymous does not overwrite attribute Authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a class `MyHub : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub` in which there are two types of method.

Type a: methods that can be called from my Angular web application. I.e., the frontend can call this method on the backend

Type b: methods that can only be called from the backend to the frontend (i.e. the frontend should not be apple to address this method).

Ideally, I'd like to decorate the class

```
[Authorize]
public class MyHub : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub>
```

Such that ALL methods are by default not callable from the frontend, and then I would like to decorate the few methods which can be called from the frontend as such:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public void AnonymousVoid() {...}
```

But the problem now is, my `AnonymousVoid` is not called any longer. I.e. the decorator `[AllowAnonymous]` doest not overrule the `[Authorize]` method as stated [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Maybe because I'm dealing with a SignalR hub rather than a controller?

How could I solve this problem without having to define `[Authorize]` for every single method as I'd like this to be the default.

Comment: Have you looked at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648623/allowanonymous-attribute-in-signalr It's not for netcore, but it may apply?

Comment: Unfortunately, the namespace `Mvc` doest not exist in `System.Web`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the following to check if the user is authenticated - you might want/be able to give a slightly enhanced/richer experience if they've authenticated:

```
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

The MSDN documentation does not make it obvious (at a glance) but 'SignalR' has it's own (same-name) 'Authorize' attribute; so if you derive from it, you can override the following method (within your custom/derived version - e.g. "SignalRAuthorizeAttribute"):

```
        public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(
                                        IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext,
                                        bool appliesToMethod)
        {
            if (hubIncomingInvokerContext.MethodDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<SignalRAllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any() ||
                hubIncomingInvokerContext.MethodDescriptor.Hub.HubType.GetCustomAttributes<SignalRAllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any())
            {
                return true;
            }

            return
                base.AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(
                        hubIncomingInvokerContext,
                        appliesToMethod);
        }
```

And therefore you can have your hubs closed by default (so that the exceptional anonymous one/s have to be actively whitelisted with a custom 'SignalRAllowAnonymousAttribute' attribute):

```
            // GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();

            var authorizeAttribute =
                new SignalRAuthorizeAttribute();

            GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(
                new AuthorizeModule(
                    globalConnectionAuthorizer: authorizeAttribute,
                    globalInvocationAuthorizer: authorizeAttribute));
```

```
    // Marker class
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class SignalRAllowAnonymousAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
```